# ¿Como cambiar el orden en gráfico de barras con matplotlib Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Elaborè un gráfico de barras combinado a partir de una tabla, el cual me indica en el eje x los meses del año, pero por defecto los ordena en orden alfabético, quisiera que se ordenaran cronológicamente (ENERO, FEBRERO...etc).

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
"AÑO": (list_año),
"MES": (list_mes),
"ACTUALIZADO": (list_actualizado),
"DESACTUALIZADO": (list_desactualizado),
"SIN IMAGEN": (list_sin_imagen)
 })

 group_sum = result.groupby(['AÑO', 'MES'])['ACTUALIZADO', 
 'DESACTUALIZADO', 'SIN IMAGEN'].sum()
  ax = group_sum.plot.bar(figsize=(15, 7), stacked=True)

  ax.set_title('titulo', fontsize=25)  # Titulo de la 
  grafica
  ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje y
  ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje x
  ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.6), fontsize=16) #ubicación leyenda
  ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=0, labelsize=15)
  ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=15)
  ax.grid(True)

  abs_values = group_sum.values
  rel_values = abs_values / abs_values.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) * 
  100

  labels = zip(abs_values.T.flatten(), rel_values.T.flatten())

  for path in ax.patches:
  abs_value, rel_value = next(labels)
  label = f"{rel_value:.2f}% ({abs_value})"
  width, height = path.get_width(), path.get_height()
  x, y = path.get_xy() 
  ax.text(x=x + width / 2, 
        y=y + height / 2, 
        s=label,
        horizontalalignment='center', 
        verticalalignment='center'
        )
        plt.show()
```

[grafico](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zpYbbCV6iN22vmK6UB8QZG42OF0j7hU9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib realmente no ordena nada, es `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` el que ordena los grupos por defecto y lo hace lexicográficamente como has observado.

Una posibilidad es hacer que tu columna `MES` sea de tipo categórico ([`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) o mediante `as_type` y `pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype`), lo cual permite a Pandas recordar el orden inicial de las categorías y ordenar en base a él.

El código sería algo así (ver advertencia debajo porque hay un bug en la versión actual de Pandas):

```
lista_meses = ['ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO',
               'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE']
meses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=lista_meses)

result = pd.DataFrame({
"AÑO": (2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018),
"MES": ("DICIEMBRE", "AGOSTO", "ENERO", "MARZO", "JUNIO", "ABRIL", "OCTUBRE"),
"ACTUALIZADO": (4, 8, 7, 12, 7, 1, 7),
"DESACTUALIZADO": (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2),
"SIN IMAGEN": (4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5)
 })

result["MES"] = result["MES"].astype(meses)
group_sum = result.groupby(['AÑO', 'MES'], observed=True)['ACTUALIZADO', 'DESACTUALIZADO', 'SIN IMAGEN'].sum()
```

> **IMPORTANTE**
>
> `groupby` ante datos categóricos agrupa usando todas las categorías posibles, no solo por las que tu DataFrame presenta. Esto se evita con el argumento `observer=True`. **Actualmente, pandas 0.24 tiene un [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25871) por el cual `groupby` pierde la capacidad de ordenar correctamente cuando se usa `observer=False`**. Este bug está corregido y será subsanado en la versión pandas 0.25. Por ahora, podemos simplemente aplicar `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values` previamente a agrupar y evitar que `Groupby` ordene el nombre de los grupos (`sort=False`):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


lista_meses = ['ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO',
               'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE']
meses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=lista_meses)

result = pd.DataFrame({
"AÑO": (2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018),
"MES": ("DICIEMBRE", "AGOSTO", "ENERO", "MARZO", "JUNIO", "ABRIL", "OCTUBRE"),
"ACTUALIZADO": (4, 8, 7, 12, 7, 1, 7),
"DESACTUALIZADO": (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2),
"SIN IMAGEN": (4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5)
 })

result["MES"] = result["MES"].astype(meses)
result.sort_values(by=['AÑO', 'MES'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
group_sum = result.groupby(['AÑO', 'MES'], observed=True, sort=False)['ACTUALIZADO', 'DESACTUALIZADO', 'SIN IMAGEN'].sum()

ax = group_sum.plot.bar(figsize=(15, 7), stacked=True)
ax.set_title('titulo', fontsize=25)  # Titulo de la grafica
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje y
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje x
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.6), fontsize=16) #ubicación leyenda
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=0, labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=15)
ax.grid(True)

abs_values = group_sum.values
rel_values = abs_values / abs_values.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) * 100

labels = zip(abs_values.T.flatten(), rel_values.T.flatten())

for path in ax.patches:
    abs_value, rel_value = next(labels)
    label = f"{rel_value:.2f}% ({abs_value})"
    width, height = path.get_width(), path.get_height()
    x, y = path.get_xy() 
    ax.text(x=x + width / 2, 
            y=y + height / 2, 
            s=label,
            horizontalalignment='center', 
            verticalalignment='center'
            )
    plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]